# Thunderbird 60 import all local emails and settings from old profile folder dir

Tags: thunderbird

I try restore from backup all my local emails and settings for Thunderbird. I have a old profile dir like:

```
/backup_ssd/home/mature/.thunderbird/tkxc6fuz.default
```

And new profile folder like:

```
/home/mature/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird/52v1yl4h.default
```

I already tried copy all from **tkxc6fuz.default** (old profile) to **52v1yl4h.default** (new profile) with root or without permissions, chmod new dir to 777, but most best result which I received when copy all files without root rights (skip part) and get accounts with message headers without bodies. I mean I see list of local emails but when click or open some i see only blank body.

Is there some solution to correctly import all necessary info from backup-ed profile folder?

Comment: Can you open the old profile when you start thunderbird with `thunderbird -p` and choose the old profile then? You may need to adjust snap permissions for thunderbird to allow access to the drive though.

Comment: @mook765 How to adjust snap permissions for thunderbird? When I copy full profile to open it with thunderbird -p from external FS I have couple permissions messages. In this case i lost part of profile. When I copy all files with 777 permissions I have empty profile.

Comment: Let's try this first please: The profile-folder should not contain any file or folder owned by root or any other user. You should check file ownership in the backed up profile, or just run `sudo chown -R $USER: /backup_ssd/home/mature/.thunderbird/tkxc6fuz.default`. Then it shouldn't be a problem to copy the profile just with user privileges.

Comment: @mook765 Yes fully copied, but now profile starts with some errors like "unable read address book"... Try mark all profile files and dirs with 777 rights - same messages. Second run of TB goes without problems but profile messages and settings empty. Help -> Troubleshooting Info - correct profile path. Something mark profile absolutely empty.

Comment: How old is the backed up profile? There could be a compatibility problem. I wouldn't change file permissions in the profile (like changig to 777), it could lead to confusion too. I assumed wrong ownership which could be introduced due to back-up method (all files owned by root) or the use of a different UID when the backup was created. For the moment I'm out of ideas...

Comment: To backup i just copy all my user dir to external ext4 HDD. Now when I try copy profile dir from this HDD I have a permissions problems. When I copy all and chmod to 777 profile stop work. I fix it with copy profile and skip not permitted files. Then manually copy all accounts from Mail dir with 777 permission. It Looks start working.